# Javascript game moving an object to coordinates

Tags: javascript, canvas

i'm making a snake game in JavaScript in which if the snake doesn't eat the apple within 5 seconds, the apple respawns to newly generated coordinates. My question is how do i animate the apple to 'move' to the new coordinates visibly, by that i mean the apple should move on the canvas to the new location, i've tried moveTo etc. but i can't find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
canv = document.getElementById("gc");
ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPush);
setInterval(game, 1000 / 15);
}
px = py = 10;
gs = tc = 20;
ax = ay = 15;
xv = yv = 0;
trail = [];
tail = 5;

var fps = 15;
var maxAppleAgeSeconds = 5;
var appleAge = 0;
var maxAppleAgeFrames = fps * maxAppleAgeSeconds;


function game() {
px += xv;
py += yv;
if (px < 0) {
px = tc - 1;
}
if (px > tc - 1) {
px = 0;
}
if (py < 0) {
py = tc - 1;
}
if (py > tc - 1) {
py = 0;
}
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
for (var i = 0; i < trail.length; i++) {
ctx.fillRect(trail[i].x * gs, trail[i].y * gs, gs - 2, gs - 2);
if (trail[i].x == px && trail[i].y == py) {
  tail = 5;
}
}
trail.push({
x: px,
y: py
});
while (trail.length > tail) {
trail.shift();
}

appleAge++;

if (ax == px && ay == py) {
tail++;
ax = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
ay = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
appleAge = 0;
} else if (appleAge > maxAppleAgeFrames) {
ax = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
ay = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
appleAge = 0;
}


ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(ax * gs, ay * gs, gs - 2, gs - 2);
}

function keyPush(evt) {
switch (evt.keyCode) {
case 37:
  xv = -1;
  yv = 0;
  break;
case 38:
  xv = 0;
  yv = -1;
  break;
case 39:
  xv = 1;
  yv = 0;
  break;
case 40:
  xv = 0;
  yv = 1;
  break;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use requestAnimationFrame (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and calculate all of the positions where the apple must be between (ax0,ay0) and (ax1,ay1). You can play around with the step size to figure out how far you want it to move in each direction per frame.

```
} else if (appleAge > maxAppleAgeFrames) {
ax1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
ay1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
appleAge = 0;
animate();
}

function animate(){
 if(ax !== ax1 || ay !== ay1){
  ax += 1 // actually calculate this value, not necessarily 1
  ay += 1 // this too
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
 }
}
```